# LSTM giving same prediction for numerical data

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I created an LSTM model for intraday stock predictions. I took the training data with the shape of (290, 4). I did all the preprocessing like Normalize the data, taking the difference, taking window size of 4.

This is a sample of my input data.

```
X = array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
   [array([ 0.19]), 0, 0, 0],
   [array([-0.35]), array([ 0.19]), 0, 0],
   ..., 
   [array([ 0.11]), array([-0.02]), array([-0.13]), array([-0.09])],
   [array([-0.02]), array([ 0.11]), array([-0.02]), array([-0.13])],
   [array([ 0.07]), array([-0.02]), array([ 0.11]), array([-0.02])]], dtype=object)

y = array([[array([ 0.19])],
   [array([-0.35])],
   [array([-0.025])],
   .....,
   [array([-0.02])],
   [array([ 0.07])],
   [array([-0.04])]], dtype=object)
```

Note: I am giving as well as predicting the difference value. So input value is between range (-0.5,0.5)

Here is my Keras LSTM model :

```
dim_in = 4
dim_out = 1

model.add(LSTM(input_shape=(1, dim_in),
                return_sequences=True, 
                units=6))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(LSTM(batch_input_shape=(1, features.shape[1],features.shape[2]),return_sequences=False,units=6))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Dense(activation='linear', units=dim_out))
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'rmsprop')


for i in range(300):
#print("Completed :",i+1,"/",300, "Steps")
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=1, verbose=2, shuffle=False)
    model.reset_states()
```

I am feeding the last sequence value of shape=(1,4) and predict the output.
This is my prediction :
    `base_value = df.iloc[290]['Close']
    prediction = []
    orig_pred = []
    input_data = np.copy(test[0,:])
    input_data = input_data.reshape(len(input_data),1) 
    for i in range(100):
        inp = input_data[i:,:]
        inp = inp.reshape(1,1,inp.shape[0])
        y = model.predict(inp)
        orig_pred.append(y[0][0])
        input_data = np.insert(input_data,[i+4],y[0][0], axis=0)
        base_value = base_value  + y
        prediction_apple.append(base_value[0][0])
    sqrt(mean_squared_error(test_output, orig_pred))`

RMSE = 0.10592485833344527

Here is the difference in prediction visualization along with stock price prediction.

[image: This is the LSTM prediction]

fig:1 -> This is the LSTM prediction

[image: Stock prediction plot]

fig:2 -> This is the Stock prediction

I am not sure why it is predicting the same output value after 10 iterations. Maybe it is the vanishing gradient problem or I am feeding fewer input data(290 approx) or problem in the model architecture. I am not sure.

Please Help how to get the reasonable result.

Thank you !!!

Comment: Try change activation

Comment: Still getting the same output.

Comment: Why are you doing this `model.fit(X, y, epochs=1, batch_size=1, verbose=2, shuffle=False)` ?.  What is `model_p` ? why are you not using `model`? Try running with multiple epochs &  fit the model ONLY once. That for loop (`for i in range(300)`) is not needed

Comment: @Kalsi Apology for writing **model_p**, I have edited that. I used for 300 epochs also still getting the same output.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? (I have similar): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56804431/mqrnn-seq2seq-lstm-mlp-model-gives-constant-predictions

Comment: There is high chance that some errors happen during data-preprocessing or loss calculation

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with Keras, but looking through your code and plots it seems like the complexity of your network might not be high enough to fit the data. Try enlarging the network with more units and also try larger window sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Because your regressor secures the minimization of the cost function by replicating the feature you give as input feature. For example if you have BTC closing value as $6340 at time t, it will go for it at t+1 or some value close to it. Ensure that you are not giving a direct numerical intuition to a regressor that what the predicted label might be, especially when working with time-series data.