# MQRNN (Seq2Seq LSTM + MLP) model gives constant predictions

Tags: python

I have a problem with MQRNN - multi-horizon quantile recurrent forecaster described here:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.11053

This is my code (short version):

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

# Structure of neural network
class MQRNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, device, output_horizon = 5, n_products = 100,  hidden_dim = 200, n_layers = 2):
        self.device = device
        super(MQRNN, self).__init__()
        # encoded = hidden_dim*2
        self.device = device
        encoded = hidden_dim
        self.output_horizon = output_horizon
        self.n_products = n_products
        self.output = output_horizon*n_products
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim

        # LAYERS
        self.LSTM_encoding = nn.LSTM(self.n_products, self.hidden_dim, self.n_layers, batch_first=True).to(self.device)

        self.MLPglob = nn.Linear(encoded, self.output+1).to(self.device)

        self.MLPlocs = nn.ModuleList([nn.Linear(2, 3) for i in range(self.output)]).to(self.device)

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        h0, c0 = (torch.zeros(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim),
                  torch.zeros(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim))
        return h0, c0

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size = x.size(0)
        _, (h, c) = self.LSTM_encoding(x, self.init_hidden(batch_size))
        # h, c = h[-1], c[-1]
        # hc = torch.cat((h,c),1) # Concatenate, łączenie macierzy w jedną.
        # hc = F.relu(hc)
        # C = self.MLPglob(hc)
        c = F.relu(h[-1])
        C = self.MLPglob(c)
        C = F.relu(C)
        C, Ca = C[:,:-1], C[:,-1:]
        C = C.view(-1,self.n_products,self.output_horizon)
        output = torch.rand(self.n_products,self.output_horizon,batch_size,3).to(self.device)  # 3 Quantyle ->  dlatego 3 na końcu.
        # output[0,0] = self.MLPlocs[0](torch.cat((C[:, 0, 0].view(-1,1), Ca),1))
        for i in range(output.size(0)):
            for j in range(output.size(1)):
                output[i,j] = self.MLPlocs[output.size(1)*i+j](torch.cat((C[:, i, j].view(-1,1), Ca),1))
        return output.permute(2,1,0,3)

# Loss function
def quantile_loss(y_pred, y_real):
    """
    :param y_pred: 4 dimensions: batch_size, horizon, n_products, n_quantiles
    :param y_real: 3 dimensions: batch_size, horizon, n_products
    :return:
    """
    y_pred = y_pred.permute(3,0,1,2)
    loss = sum(sum(sum(2*(0.1*F.relu(y_real - y_pred[0])+0.9*F.relu(y_pred[0]-y_real)+
                    0.5*F.relu(y_real - y_pred[1]) + 0.5 * F.relu(y_pred[1] - y_real) +
                    0.9 * F.relu(y_real - y_pred[2]) + 0.1 * F.relu(y_pred[2] - y_real)))))

    loss = loss/sum(sum(sum(y_real)))

    return loss

device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Sample data
x_1 = torch.FloatTensor([[[5000],[5043],[5015],[5100],[5109],[5150],[5183],[5222],[5243],[5259],[5298],
                     [5350],[5340],[5392],[5422],[5465],[5492],[5520],[5589],[5643]]]).to(device)
y_1 = torch.FloatTensor([[[5700],[5743],[5798],[5782],[5834]]]).to(device)

x_2 = torch.FloatTensor([[[5000],[5050],[5100],[5150],[5200],[5250],[5300],[5350],[5400],[5450],[5500],
                     [5550],[5600],[5650],[5700],[5750],[5800],[5850],[5900],[5950]]]).to(device)
y_2 = torch.FloatTensor([[[6000],[6050],[6100],[6150],[6200]]]).to(device)

x_3 = torch.FloatTensor([[[423],[413],[400],[392],[379],[354],[359],[352],[320],[298],[250],
                     [254],[243],[212],[2140],[201],[204],[254],[214],[355]]]).to(device)
y_3 = torch.FloatTensor([[[241],[231],[231],[221],[150]]]).to(device)

xx = torch.cat((x_1, x_3)).permute(2,1,0)
yy = torch.cat((y_1, y_3)).permute(2,1,0)
xx_2 = xx*10
yy_2 = yy*10

hidden_dim = 10
n_output = 5
n_products = xx.size(2)

model = MQRNN(device=device, n_products=n_products, n_layers=1,
              output_horizon=n_output, hidden_dim=hidden_dim)
model.to(device)

ADAM = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0126) #  lr=100.0126

n_epochs = 1600

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    pred = model(xx)
    loss = quantile_loss(pred, yy)
    # ADAM.zero_grad()
    # loss.backward()
    # ADAM.step()

    pred = model(xx_2)
    loss += quantile_loss(pred, yy_2)
    ADAM.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    ADAM.step()

    if epoch % 100 == 0:
        print('Epoch: {}/{}.............'.format(epoch, n_epochs), end=' ')
        print("Loss: {:.4f}".format(loss.item()))
```

I have of course different real data, but on this sample my problem looks clearly.

First problem is that model learns very very slow, there is not any big decline of loss on the beginning (with normal learning rate e.g. 0.0126). In fact I need to set very big learning rate - 100 on the beginning to make learning faster. If I use normal learning rate results are similiar but it take a long time.

From Console:

```py
Epoch: 0/1600............. Loss: 6.0000
Epoch: 100/1600............. Loss: 2.7139
Epoch: 200/1600............. Loss: 2.7096
Epoch: 300/1600............. Loss: 2.7103
Epoch: 400/1600............. Loss: 2.7096
Epoch: 500/1600............. Loss: 2.7085
Epoch: 600/1600............. Loss: 2.7090
Epoch: 700/1600............. Loss: 2.7099
Epoch: 800/1600............. Loss: 2.7082
Epoch: 900/1600............. Loss: 2.7098
Epoch: 1000/1600............. Loss: 2.7119
Epoch: 1100/1600............. Loss: 2.7107
Epoch: 1200/1600............. Loss: 2.7097
Epoch: 1300/1600............. Loss: 2.7105
Epoch: 1400/1600............. Loss: 2.7088
Epoch: 1500/1600............. Loss: 2.7108
```

Second, and **more important** problem does not react to the structure of input data.
I gave two tensors, where second is the first times 10 as input data, and as you can see network get to some local minimum finding the same output for every input.

```py
model(xx)
tensor([[[[5665.4424, 5699.3140, 6114.7104],
          [ 215.9684,  236.8552,  655.0918]],
         [[5719.0410, 5759.0107, 6109.4790],
          [ 121.5060,  241.7687,  653.9695]],
         [[5693.7803, 5769.5596, 6224.1328],
          [ 237.4870,  241.9645,  652.4545]],
         [[5752.0298, 5783.4038, 6215.9785],
          [ 183.8642,  209.5887,  656.7449]],
         [[5815.0850, 5814.8887, 6209.8477],
          [ 120.6066,  148.9004,  677.6846]]]], grad_fn=<PermuteBackward>)
model(xx_2)
tensor([[[[5665.4424, 5699.3140, 6114.7104],
          [ 215.9684,  236.8552,  655.0918]],
         [[5719.0410, 5759.0107, 6109.4790],
          [ 121.5060,  241.7687,  653.9695]],
         [[5693.7803, 5769.5596, 6224.1328],
          [ 237.4870,  241.9645,  652.4545]],
         [[5752.0298, 5783.4038, 6215.9785],
          [ 183.8642,  209.5887,  656.7449]],
         [[5815.0850, 5814.8887, 6209.8477],
          [ 120.6066,  148.9004,  677.6846]]]], grad_fn=<PermuteBackward>)
yy
tensor([[[5700.,  241.],
         [5743.,  231.],
         [5798.,  231.],
         [5782.,  221.],
         [5834.,  150.]]])
yy_2
tensor([[[57000.,  2410.],
         [57430.,  2310.],
         [57980.,  2310.],
         [57820.,  2210.],
         [58340.,  1500.]]])
```

How can I solve this problem to get reasonable predictions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you found the solution to this?
I found a working implementation here: https://github.com/awslabs/gluon-ts/blob/0d963f7dc55ef866d86e33633a28d57dfab33adb/src/gluonts/model/seq2seq/_mq_dnn_estimator.py
but would love a PyTorch simpler lighter/version.